# C++ creating a class object

Tags: c++, class, object

I am having issues creating an object for my class, I am getting errors trying to create the class object with the defined data members.

```
// class header for employee
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
class Employee
{
private:
    std::string name;
    int empnum;
    std::string address;
    std::string phone;
    double hourwage;
    double hoursworked;
public:
    Employee(void);
    Employee(int, std::string , std::string, std::string, double, double);
    double gethourwage () const;
    double gethoursworked () const;
    double printcheck () const;
    std::string getphone() const;
    std::string getname() const;
    std::string getaddress() const;
};
// end of header

// employee class.cpp
#include "Employee.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

Employee::Employee(void)
{
    int empnum = 0;
    double hourwage = 0.0;
    double hoursworked = 0.0;
}
Employee::Employee(int num, std::string nme, std::string addres, std::string phon, double hourpay, double hrswrked)
{
    num = empnum;
    nme = name;
    addres = address;
    phon = phone;
    hourpay = hourwage;
    hrswrked = hoursworked;
}

double Employee::gethourwage() const
{
    return hourwage;
}
double Employee::gethoursworked() const
{
    return hoursworked;
}
double Employee::printcheck() const
{
    double pay = 0.0;
    double hrspay = hourwage;
    double hrswork = hoursworked;
    return hoursworked;

}
// end of employee.cpp
// main
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include "Employee.h"

using namespace std;
int main( )
{
    int num1 = 10210;
    double hourwage = 20.2;
    double hourworked = 32.3;
    string steve;
    Employee emp(num1, steve, 58s200w, 90210, hourwage, hourworked);
    cout << "" << emp.getaddress();

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
} // end of main
```

"Employee emp(num1, steve, 58s200w, 90210, hourwage, hourworked);" towards the bottom is the line I am having the issue with. I am not sure if I am entering it in the wrong order, or something else.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `58s200w` is neither a string nor a valid numeric constant. Where do you initialize `steve` with a proper value?

Comment: That was just me putting things in to test the object, I should have deleted them before i copied the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should enter strings in double quotes:

```
Employee emp(num1, "steve", "58s200w", "90210", hourwage, hourworked);
```

**Edit 1 (tried to explain the difference between `const char *` and `std::string`, as @Alex suggested)**

Literal strings in the snippet above are of type `const char *`, which is a low-level entity inherited from the C language. `const char *` is a **pointer** to memory area which holds consecutive values of type `const char`.

`std::string` is a higher-level wrapper around C-style strings intended to provide more «user-friendly» API and solve some problems of C-style strings (e.g., dynamic allocation and automatic memory cleanup).

Because the `std::string` class has a constructor which takes a `const char *` parameter, literal strings passed to the `Employee` constructor are implicitly converted to `std::string`'s

Comment: Might be worth explaining the difference between `const char *` and `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

Your Employee class constructor is

```
Employee::Employee(int num, std::string nme, std::string addres, std::string phon, double hourpay, double hrswrked)
```

and you are calling it as

```
Employee emp(num1, steve, 58s200w, 90210, hourwage, hourworked);
```

You can directly see the difference, Employee class constructor expecting 2nd, 3rd and 4th argument as String. So you have to pass these arguments as string. Either you have to declare string as hourwage, hourworked variables as you defined or you have to pass arguments as nameless above explained.